# How to remove wordpress theme to override plugin css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

guys!
I have a wordpress website that has installed Kalixo Magazine theme. I tried to install several widget menu plugins with interesting designs, but always the design( i think the css and js/jquery) is the default one from the theme.
How can I stop my theme to override the css of widget menu plugin so I can have a unique menu on my sidebar ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has anything to do with your theme, rather it is with the plugins. I suspect that the plugin authors has not set a priority when they registered/hooked the stylesheets to `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. This will cause the plugin style to load to early, and all styles later gets overridden by the themes' stylesheet

I would suggest, create a child theme, and then copy the complete stylesheet from the plugin to your child themes' stylesheet. The child themes' stylesheet will be loaded lastn so give this a try

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this is de_register that plugin CSS from your WordPress site and then add the CSS of that plugin into your main style.css file. This way it will take only a single css file to render all the styling and will not overload your website.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'contact-form-7' );
    //wp_deregister_style( 'digg-digg' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wp125style' );
}
```

and then load your style.css file using script_enque method for better result

Answer (score -2):

you can fix this problem customize by your plugin style sheet. if you don't know your plugin, you can find it in this path wordpress\wp-content\plugins ....

Comment: BAD BAD idea. Never ever change plugin files.

Comment: sorry pieter . may i know why we can't change style sheet of plugin ?

Comment: If I may ask, what will happen when you update your plugin, which will become compulsary at some stage?

Comment: it's ok friend. your right . sorry for my answer. :)

Comment: To answer your and mine question, once you update your plugin, all that customizations will be lost. Then you will be back to square one again